# Angular UI accordion directive not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to angular and I was trying to add the accordion, but I keep getting this error from the console. **"Controller 'accordion', required by directive 'accordionGroup', can't be found!"** I downloaded the custom build version of the angular ui. I injected the 'ui.bootstrap' into the module like this.

`var app = angular.module('MenuApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

**In my index.html I added the following code to load the files to the head section.**

`<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

**In the body, I loaded the custom js file like this.**
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/angularjs@1.3.14(angular.min.js),angular.ui-router@0.2.13(angular-ui-router.min.js)"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js"></script>`

**In my menu.html, I am loading the accordion menu like this.**
`<accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>`

So my question is, how do I fix this issue? I have been reading the docs on their website and somehow I can't seem to understand how to fix the error. I know I am probably missing something, but I'm not really sure at this point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compile error, accordion controller required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199937/compile-error-accordion-controller-required)

Comment: Looks like the solution will likely be the same as in linked question from @sheilak

Comment: Thanks, but I took a look at the other question, and tried their solution. Unfortunately, still no luck .

Comment: Is it still the same error? Could you update the question with your menu.html code after adding accordion directive?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did fix the issue. I looked at my code and added the controller into my js file. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look closely at the CSS & JS references, but for the HTML, it seems like you forgot the root `<accordion>` tag.  Directly from the UI-Bootstrap docs, you need a structure like:

```
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group>
      .......
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group>
      .......
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

If this helps, please accept the answer!

Comment: glad to help - if that fixes your problem, could you 'accept' my answer?  I'm trying to build up my rep  :)

Answer (score 0):

I loaded this version 0.12 of ui.bootstrap because the animation was broken in version 0.13.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>`

I copied a plunker file I found with nested accordion menus and then I edited it to my liking and it finally worked. I was so ecstatic.

`<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

    <accordion-group is-open="status.open"  is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
        <accordion-heading>
            TITLE HERE
        </accordion-heading>
        DATA HERE
    </accordion>`

I made sure to add the files in the head section too. It worked just fine. 
`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>`