# Issues with Angular UI Accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having some issues with the Angular accordion.  Here is the HTML/Angular code:

```
<accordion id="accordion1" close-others="true">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header" is-open="false" ng-repeat="service in userPF.custom.services">
        <accordion-heading><input type="checkbox" name="status" disabled>On <input type="checkbox" name="status" disabled checked>Off {{service.name}} {{service.desc}}</accordion-heading>
        <div class="secondary" ng-repeat="fields in userPF.custom.fields">
            <span ng-show="checkForMatch(service.name, fields.services)">
            <span ng-repeat="value in fields.values">
        {{value.name}} {{value.desc}}<br>
            </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'accordionGroup', required by
>   directive 'accordionHeading', can't be found!

UI seems to be linked correctly but just in case, here's the appropriate line:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('LSPortal', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'checkBoxFilters', 'ui.bootstrap']) //...etc...
```

Looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199937/compile-error-accordion-controller-required) before asking and modified my code accordingly:

Would post a fiddle but the controller is very, very long and mostly irrelevant to this specific problem.  But will do if needed.

Comment: Could the problem be that I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap elsewhere in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have to be careful how you use UI Bootstrap with Bootstrap and jQuery with the jQuery lite that's already included in Angular.

I found that answer [here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together).